# DB Design - multiple text fields

Tags: php, database

I have a table with products and their descriptions in several languages. For now the table structure is like this

**tblProducts**

```
productId INT PK AI
productDesc_en VARCHAR
productDesc_de VARCHAR
productDesc_it VARCHAR
```

and so on. Where en is for English, de is for German

So visitor according to his language setting, sees description on his language.

Just wondering, are there any benefits in storing data like this instead?

**tblProducts**

```
productId INT PK AI
```

**tblProductDesc_en**

```
descId INT PK AI
tblProducts_productId INT FK
description VARCHAR
```

**tblProductDesc_de**

```
descId INT PK AI
tblProducts_productId INT FK
description VARCHAR
```

**tblProductDesc_it**

```
descId INT PK AI
tblProducts_productId INT FK
description VARCHAR
```

The pro(s) i see in this solution:

1. Easier to maintain from DB perspective
2. Less memory used when instantiating object from DB record (since only required language
   will be stored within an object)

The con(s):

1. Will have to use JOIN(s) to fetch required data which may hit performance;
2. More complicated getters and setters from within a class

Anything else?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just have one `tblProductDesc`, and add a column for `tblProductDesc_lang`? And save a new row for each language?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, what difference it makes from second solution? I will still have to use join to fetch a correct result. Besides, i will have to store lots of empty columns, where there's no description in certain language in it.

Comment: By second you solution, you're referring to the one in your question? You're talking about having multiple tables with the same exact columns, the only difference being an attribute about the row (the language). You don't have to have any empty rows (not sure why you think that). When you save the description, add a row for each language available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having only one extra table with a flag for the language would be a good solution very close to normalization providing a more solid db schemma when new language is added.

It would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `language` (
  `prodID`  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  ,
  `desc` varchar(30) null  ,
  `lang`  char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`prodID`,`lang`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`prodID`)
        REFERENCES `product` (`prodID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

The foreign key would provide integrity when product are deleted also allowing insertion when product exists only.

The composite primary key will make so that a description for **a language and product** is stored only once.

In terms of dependency this primary key looks good to me, recalling lectures on db it is good because the non primary key fields are depended to both parts of the primary key, I mean need  both parts to be identified.

You have the same field as part of primary key and foreign key, it is like borrowing this part of the primary key.

========== Edit 1 (Nothing changed above) ==============
I would replace `Null` with `Not Null` on desc field. Then if a product exists and a description not this means no description available. It is my opinion that there is no reason to allow for null desc above.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest con for your existing situation is when you need to add a language(s). The changes in your current solution are likely to be more extensive and more brittle than if you have the languages are separated out.

There is an alternative solution that is half way between your two suggestions, and which reduces the impact of the cons of your suggested solution. This is to have one language as the default in your product description, and have alternative languages in separate tables. This does assume that the majority of users will be accessing your database one language.

Comment: with your solution - this assumes that I am fetching a description within a constructor method? Then if description doesn't match language, I will have to either call separate method to fetch correct description, or somehow create dynamic query to detect language during constructor execution. I'm afraid, this will make it  more complicated. Another pro I see in the second approach, is that I don't really have to get a description from constructor (I normally try to give constructors as little arguments as possible), but to fetch a description from separate method, depending on language.